# Enabling RestKit logging

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

I'm having trouble actually accessing the RestKit function:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network*", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

It still says "Use of unresolved identifier" for the actual function.  RestKit is working otherwise but I'm trying to log my requests so I can see what's going on.

Any idea as to what I'm missing?  I've tried searching other questions but they only talk about how to actually enable logging.

Comment: Are you importing <RestKit/RestKit.h>?

Answer (score -2):

First in the `Header.h` file declare an init method like this

```
+(void)init;
```

In the Header.m, in the implementation of method above, set Restkit log:

```
+(void)init{
      RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network*", RKLogLevelTrace);
}
```

Finally in your `AppDelegate` where you init your application properties you can call `Header.init();`.